# How to pass large data from jsp to servlet

Tags: jsp

I want to pass large amount of data from a jsp page to a servlet, the data to be passed is an HTML page with all its tags, and it is too big to be passed in the url, what other way can i use to effectively pass this value. I need to pass this way periodically (something like an autosave functionality of a page).

The data is string.

Is there a solution using jquery?

Comment: Related thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826524/http-request-post-field-size-limit-request-binaryread-in-jsps and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943477/is-there-a-max-size-for-post-parameter-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO you should POST your data . If you want to do it periodically then use AJAX post.

See [HTTP Form POST Request using AJAX and Servlet](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/ajax/http-form-post-request-using-ajax-and-servlet)